# Linq in For Loop

Tags: c#

Is this linq statement gonna be executed everytime in each loop? Does somehow the for loop store the linq result?

```
for(int i = 0; i < mylist.Where(x => x > 10).ToList().Count; i++)
```

Sorry in case of a duplicate

Comment: There's a built-in `Count` method - `mylist.Count(x => x > 10)`.

Comment: Anyway, condition will be executed multiple times = performance issue.

Comment: will build-in count method be executed on every loop?

Comment: `i < mylist.Where(x => x > 10).ToList().Count` whole condition is executed every iteration.

Comment: _"Sorry in case of a duplicate"_ - please try to search first then. I found this one on _"C# for loop condition evaluation every iteration"_, of course using Google and not the site search.

Comment: @CodeCaster well yea, its too late now. duplicate aint that bad, at least more keywords in google for future searchers :)

Answer (score 4):

I ran the following code in LINQPad:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10.Dump(); i++)
{
}
```

The result was:

[image]

So, i think the answer is yes, it will execute it multiple times.

Comment: An interesting approach, but it proves little in fact. Imagine if `Where` method looked something like (I know it doesn't, but still): `public IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> condition) { if (alreadyCalculated) return alreadyComputedArray; /* complex calculations */ alreadyCalculated = true; }`

Comment: @decPL Do you think it would not evaluate each time in this case? The question was if the code would be executed each time.

Comment: No, the question was whether the LINQ statement is executed. I'd argue that if LINQ worked differently (i.e. it was somehow precompiled), there would be no LINQ execution.

Comment: @decPL I tried `for(int i = 0; i < Enumerable.Range(0,10).Where(x=>x>i).Count().Dump(); i++)` . The results where `9,8,7,6,5,4`. This shows it is executed each time, no?

Comment: I'm not questioning your results - yes, you're correct, LINQ statement is executed each time. I am however questioning your methodology, which is flawed. What you did is similar to: Question: Does a cat fly? Answer: Yes! As you can see attached - I've thrown a pigeon in the air and it did fly. So yes, animals are flying.

Comment: @decPL HAHAHAHAHA.... yes, i do get what you mean.  Well, i think it was a practical way of checking this. I really would like to see you try throwing an elephant though... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it would work but I would suggest to better try to store it in a int variable

```
int k = mylist.Where(x => x > 10).ToList().Count; 
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
```

This makes it more readable

Comment: What if he modifies the list, and he wants after each iteration to check the count ?

Comment: Better use `Enumerable.Count` if you don't need the list. `int count=mylist.Count(x => x > 10)`. It's also worth mentioning that `foreach` does not execute it on every iteration.

Comment: @NovitchiS condition should be constant (IMHO) - I think that it's bad pratice to modyify condition in `for` loop as far as variable. If he would like to modyify collection, I think that while loop would be a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this:

```
mylist.Where(x => x > 10)
      .Select((x,index) => ExecuteYourFunction(x, index));
```

Or if your method has not any return value:

```
mylist.Where(x => x > 10)
      .Select((x,index) => new { Index = index, Value= x })
      .ToList()
      .Foreach(myType => ExecuteYourFunction(myType.Name, myType.Index));
```

Comment: I probably shouldn't be commenting, as I'm the first to jump the if-it-can-be-done-in-LINQ-do-it! gun, but that's neither more readable (and that's comming from a LINQ fanatic), nor performs better.

Comment: Also has pointless `ToList`s in the middle of it. And the first one doesn't execute anything until you iterate it.

Comment: @Rawling Thanks, removed in both cases.